# using javascript inline in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I have an array in my controller containing date-objects called $scope.events. I would like to iterate these events and and print them out in a certain format, which I use momentjs for.

Now the thing is, I cannot get it to actually use momentjs.

I have tried the following:

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="ev in events">
    <td>{{ moment(ev).format("HH") }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

but this just prints an empty cell.

So my question is, how do I use javascript, momentjs, inline in my angular-binding ?

thanks

Thomas

Comment: Will work only if `moment` is declared as a member of `$scope`: `$scope.moment = moment;`.

Comment: Also, just as a note on good AngularJS practice, it might be worth wrapping momentjs in an Angular service and using that.

Comment: try as well:  `<td>{{ moment(ev) | date 'HH' }}</td>` where `moment` under `$scope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `moment` is a property of `window`, you'll need to create a reference in this object's `$scope` that references `moment`.

Very simply:

```
$scope.moment = window.moment;
```

Here's a plunkr showing internal `$scope` methods vs. a `$scope` property referencing a method on `window`:

http://embed.plnkr.co/PWFK80/preview

That's the simple answer, but you'd likely want to wrap this library into its own directive or service, so that you could use it without coupling higher-level objects to the window object unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code in a function in your controller for a quick answer.

```
controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.moment = moment;
});
```

*I edited this to match a comment by @Stewie because it looks better*

and in your html:

```
<td>{{moment(ev, 'HH'}}</td>
```

Or make a service/directive for `moment` for something better.